# How to use Sproutcore 2.0 with Twitter bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sproutcore-2, ember.js

I create topbar menu using twitter-bootstrap and It working fine

```
.topbar
  .topbar-inner
    .container-fluid
      {{#view Mediawrap.menuView id="menuView"}}
      = link_to 'Mediawrap', root_path, {:class=>"brand"}
      %ul.nav
        %li.menu
          = link_to 'Search', "#", {:class=>"menu"}
          %ul.menu-dropdown
            %li
              = link_to "Hide date search", "#"
            %li
              = link_to "Hide index search", "#"
            %li
              = link_to "Hide advance search", "#"
            %li
              = link_to "Clear search", "#"
            %li.divider
            %li
              = link_to 'Save to new folder ...', "#"
            %li
              = link_to 'Replace a folder', "#"
      {{/view}}
```

until I try to add Sproutcore to page. My dropdown are stop working.
I think It's because "$(document).ready(function()" is calling before Sproutcore generate HTML tag.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("bank");
  $(".topbar").dropdown();
});
```

How do I call command in document.ready after sproutcore finished generate HTML tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might also try using a ready callback inside your application:

```
App = SC.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    this._super();
    $(".topbar").dropdown();
  }
});
```

I think it's a mistake that you have to call this._super() here, and will fix it soon.

Comment: Which approach would you consider to be more idiomatic ember.js: Using the application's "ready" callback, or the view's "didInsertElement" callback? My guess is that it makes sense to use "ready" for fairly global types of initialization, and "didInsertElement" for view specific initialization (such as this dropdown menu example, or things like applying jQuery-UI sortable to a list, etc.). Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Call Twitter Bootstrap script after generate Sproutcore by "didInsertElement" call back

```
Mediawrap.menuView = SC.View.extend({
  color: 'blue',

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this._super();
    $(".topbar").dropdown();
  }
})
```

"didInsertElement" < is not in online document but you can generate it by your self

Comment: You don't normally have to call this._super() inside lifecycle callbacks.